# Percorrer uma lista de string e exibir o resultado de 2 em 2

Tags: python, lista

em determinada parte do código, preciso percorrer uma lista com valores de string. Porém a exibição desse valores precisa ser de **2 em 2**, ao invés de 1 a 1. Estou usando a versão Python 3.

Exemplo exibindo 1 a 1:

```
 seguidores = ["teste", 'teste2', 'teste3', 'teste4', 'teste5']
     
 for i in seguidores:
    print(i)
```

No caso preciso que o print(i) imprimisse 2 resultado de cada vez da lista de seguidores.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução pra isso é utilizar [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) da lista.

```py
seguidores = ["teste", 'teste2', 'teste3', 'teste4', 'teste5']

tamanho = len(seguidores)

# Índice aumenta em 2 a cada iteração
for indice in range(0, tamanho, 2):
  # Mostra os resultados a partir de índice
  # até índice + 2
  print(seguidores[indice : indice + 2])
```

Comment: Show adaptei ao restante do código e está rodando aqui. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

```
seguidores = ["teste", 'teste2', 'teste3', 'teste4', 'teste5', 'teste6', 'teste7', 'teste8', 'teste9']

for i in range(0, len(seguidores), 2):
    try:
        print(f'posicao: {i} e valor:{seguidores[i]} - posicao: {i+1} e valor:{seguidores[i+1]} ')
    except:
        print(f'posicao: {i} e valor:{seguidores[i]}')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show adaptei ao restante do código e está rodando aqui. Muito obrigado

Comment: opa, de nada...